# Using 'ash' in LISP to perform a binary search?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, land-of-lisp

So, I'm reading Land of Lisp now, and Lisp is turning out to be quite different than other programming languages that I've seen.

Anyways, the book provides some code that we're meant to enter into the CLISP REPL:

```
(defparameter *small* 1)
(defparameter *big* 100)

(defun guess-my-number ()
    (ash (+ *small* *big*) -1))

(defun smaller ()
    (setf *big* (1- (guess-my-number)))
    (guess-my-number))

(defun bigger ()
    (setf *small* (1+ (guess-my-number)))
    (guess-my-number))
```

Now, the basic goal is to create a number guessing game wherein the user/player chooses a number, and then the computer tries to guess the number. It performs a "binary search", to find the player's number, by having the player report whether the computer-guessed number is higher or lower than the player's number.

I'm a little bit confused about the `ash` function. It's my understanding that this is vital to the binary search, but I'm not really sure why. The book somewhat explains what it does, but it's a little confusing.

What does the `ash` function do? Why is it passed the parameters of `*small*` added to `*big*` and `-1`? How does it work? What purpose does it serve to the binary search?

Comment: See the HyperSpec entry on [**ASH**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_ash.htm): "ash performs the arithmetic shift operation on the binary representation of integer, which is treated as if it were binary."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google gives you [this page](http://www.psg.com/~dlamkins/sl/chapter18.html) which explains that `ash` is an arithmetic shift operation. So `(ash x -1)` shift `x` by one bit to the right, so gives its integer half.

Comment: So it effectively finds the average of `*small*` and `*big*`, but it returns a whole number rather than a floating point?

Comment: Yes, and it needs `*small*` and `*big*` to be integers.

Comment: It is actually not necessary to use `ash` to achieve integer division in Lisp, there are also the `floor` and `truncate` functions. You could therefore replace `(ash x -1)` with `(floor x 2)`.

Comment: If you'd used the normal division operator, it would've returned a rational rather than a float (so `(/2 5)` is actually 2/5 rather than 0.4, might be significant, since floats have assorted round-off issues that rationals do not; on the other hand rationals do not usually have dedicated accelerators).

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to [Basile Starynkevitch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/841108/basile-starynkevitch) for the help on this one...

Anyhow, `ash` performs an [arithmetic shift operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift).

In the case of `(ash x -1)` it shifts `x` by one bit to the right, which ultimately returns the integer half.

For example, consider the binary number `1101`. `1101` in binary is equivalent to `13` in decimal, which can be calculated like so:

```
8 * 1 = 8
4 * 1 = 4
2 * 0 = 0
1 * 1 = 1

8 + 4 + 0 + 1 = 13
```

Running `(ash 13 -1)` would look at the binary representation of 13, and perform an arithmetic shift of -1, shifting all the bits to the right by 1. This would produce a binary output of `110` (chopping off the `1` at the end of the original number). `110` in binary is equivalent to `6` in decimal, which can be calculated like so:

```
4 * 1 = 4
2 * 1 = 2
1 * 0 = 0

4 + 2 + 0 = 6
```

Now, 13 divided by 2 is not equivalent to 6, it's equivalent to 6.5, however, since it will return the integer half, 6 is the acceptable answer.

This is because binary is base 2.

Answer (score 1):

> Q. What does the ash function do? Why is it passed the parameters of *small* added to *big* and -1? How does it work? What purpose does it serve to the binary search?

It does operation of of [shifting bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Bit_shifts), more precisely [Arithmetic shifting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift) as explained/represented graphically for particular case of Lisp:

```
> (ash 51 1)
102
```

When you do `(ash 51 1)` it will shift the binary of 51 i.e `110011`  by 1 bit place  towards **left side** and results in `1100110` which gives you 102 in decimal. (process of binary to decimal conversion is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8635000/4493879))

[image]

Here it *adds* `0` in the vacant most right place (called **L**east **S**ignificant **B**it).

```
> (ash 51 -1)
25
```

When you do `(ash 51 -1)` it will shift the binary of 51 i.e `110011` by 1 bit place  towards **right side** (negative value stands for opposite direction) and results in `11001` which gives you 102 in decimal.

[image]

Here it *discards* the redundant LSB.

In particular example of "guess-my-number" game illustrated in Land of Lisp, we are interested in halving the range or to average. So, `(ash (+ *small* *big*) -1))` will do halving of 100+1 = 100 / 2 to result in 50. We can check it as follows:

```
> (defparameter *small* 1)
*SMALL*
> (defparameter *big* 100)
*BIG*
> 
(defun guess-my-number ()
    (ash (+ *small* *big*) -1))
GUESS-MY-NUMBER
> (guess-my-number)
50
```

An interesting thing to notice is you can double the value of integer by left shifting by 1 bit and (approximately) halve it by right shifting by 1 bit.