# When to use defparameter instead of setf?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, variable-assignment

I'm currently reading the book `Land of LISP`, and I'm just working through the first chapter. In there, there is a little program written where the computer guesses numbers between 1 and 100. Its code is as follows:

```
(defparameter *small* 1)
(defparameter *big* 100)

(defun guess-my-number ()
    (ash (+ *small* *big*) -1))

(defun smaller ()
    (setf *big* (1- (guess-my-number)))
    (guess-my-number))

(defun bigger ()
    (setf *small* (1+ (guess-my-number)))
    (guess-my-number))

(defun start-over ()
    (defparameter *small* 1)
    (defparameter *big* 100)
    (guess-my-number))
```

So far, I understand what happens, and [Using 'ash' in LISP to perform a binary search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634799/using-ash-in-lisp-to-perform-a-binary-search) helped me a lot in this. Nevertheless there's one thing left that puzzles me: As far as I have learned, you use `setf` to assign values to variables, and `defparameter` to initially define variables. I also have understood the difference between `defparameter` and `defvar`(at least I believe I do ;-)).

So now my question is: If I should use `setf` to assign a value to a variable once it had been initialized, why does the `start-over` function use `defparameter` and not `setf`? Is there a special reason for this, or is this just sloppiness?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function is just:

```
(defun start-over ()
  (setf *small* 1)
  (setf *big* 100)
  (guess-my-number))
```

It is already declared to be a special global variable. No need to do it inside the function again and again.

You *CAN* use `DEFPARAMETER` inside a function, but it is bad style.

`DEFPARAMETER` is for declaring global special variables and optional documentation for them. Once. If you need to do it several times, it's mostly done when a whole file or system gets reloaded. The file compiler also recognizes it in top-level position as a *special* declaration for a dynamically bound variable.

Example:

File 1:

```
(defparameter *foo* 10)

(defun foo ()
  (let ((*foo* ...))
    ...))
```

File 2:

```
(defun foo-start ()
  (defparameter *foo* 10))

(defun foo ()
  (let ((*foo* ...))
    ...))
```

If Lisp compiles File 1 fresh with `compile-file`, the compiler recognizes the `defparameter` and in the following `let` we have a dynamic binding.

If Lisp compiles File 2 fresh with `compile-file`, the compiler doesn't recognize the `defparameter` and in the following `let` we have a lexical binding. If we compile it again, from this state, we have a dynamic binding.

So here version 1 is better, because it is easier to control and understand.

In your example `DEFPARAMETER` appears multiple times, which is not useful. I might ask, *where is the variable defined* and the answer would point to multiple source locations...

So: make sure that your program elements get mostly defined *ONCE* - unless you have a good  reason not to do so.

Answer (score 3):

So you have global variables. Those can be defined by `defconstant` (for really non-chainging stuff), `defparameter` (a constant that you can change) and `defvar` (a variable that does not overwrite if you `load`.

You use `setf` to *alter* the state of lexical as well and global variables. `start-over` could have used `setf` since the code doesn't really define it but change it. If you would have replaced `defparameter` with `defvar` `start-over` would stop working.

```lisp
(defparameter *par* 5)
(setf *par* 6)
(defparameter *par* 5)
*par* ; ==> 5


(defvar *var* 5)
(setf *var* 6)
(defvar *var* 5)
*var* ; ==> 6
```

`defconstant` is like `defparameter` except once defined the CL implementation is free to inline it in code. Thus if you redefine a constant you need to redefine all functions that uses it or else it might use the old value.

```lisp
(defconstant +c+ 5)
(defun test (x)
  (+ x +c+))
(test 1)             ; ==> 6
(defconstant +c+ 6)
(test 1)             ; ==> 6 or 7
(defun test (x)
  (+ x +c+))
(test 1)             ; ==> 7
```

Comment: The standard doesn't demand that an implementation will inline `defconstant`. It's only required that the value of the variable will never change ([constant variable](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_c.htm#constant_variable)).

Comment: @schaueho Reworded. Some implementations might treat `defconstant` as `defparameter` and it will still be according to standard since it's the programmer that is refrained from redefining.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, one would use `defvar` to initialy define global variables. The difference between `defvar` and `defparameter` is subtle, cf. the [section in the CLHS](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defpar.htm) and this plays a role here: `defparameter` (in contrast to `defvar`) assigns the value anew, whereas `defvar` would leave the old binding in place. 
To address what to use: In general, `defvar` and friends are used as top-level forms, not inside some function (closures being the most notable exception in the context of `defun`). I would use `setf`, not `defparameter`.

Comment: Any idea why the LoL author used the `defparameter`s inside those functions?

Comment: This `start-over` function does some sort of reset. It's intent is to do away with any changes that might have occurred in the mean time. `defparameter` is often used instead of `defvar` to indicate that this variable can, but should not be set. So, to me the code tries to communicate that setting `*small*` to 1 here is not a normal operation, but a reset. A normal `setf` doesn't have the same stumbling effect. I have to admit I don't find this `defparameter` usage particularly appealing (but I don't like such reset functions either, FWIW).

Comment: Yeah, I don't think it's a great to use it like this, either.  If a program uses a parameter variable like this, there's nothing wrong with setting it with `setf`, if that's what needs to happen.  I just wanted to hear "this isn't idiomatic," I guess. :)

Answer (score 0):

For a beginner symbols, variables, etc. can be a bit surprising.  Symbols are surprisingly featureful. Just to mention a few things you can ask a symbol for it's symbol-value, symbol-package, symbol-name, symbol-function etc.  In addition symbols can have a varying amount of information declared about them, for example a type, that provides advice the compile might leverage to create better code.  This is true of all symbols, for example *, the symbol you use for multiplication has a symbol-function that does that multiplication.  It also has a symbol-value, i.e. the last value returned in the current REPL.

One critical bit of declarative information about symbols is if they are "special."  (Yeah, it's a dumb name.)  For good reasons it's good practice to declare all global symbols to be special. `defvar`, `defparameter`, and `defconstant` do that for you. We have a convention that all special variables are spelled with * on the front and back, `*standard-output*` for example.  This convention is so common that some compilers will warn you if you neglect to follow it.

One benefit of declaring a symbol as special is that it will suppress the warning you get when you misspell a variable in your functions.  For example `(defun faster (how-much) (incf *speed* hw-much))` will generate a warning about `hw-much`.

The coolest feature of a symbol that is special is that it is managed with what we call dynamic scoping, in contrast to lexical scope.  Recall how * has the value of the last result in the REPL.  Well in some implementations you can have multiple REPLs (each running in it's own thread) each will want to have it's own *, it's own `*standard-output*`, etc. etc. This is easy in Common Lisp; the threads establish a "dynamic extent" and bind the specials that should be local to that REPL.

So yes, you could just `setf *small*` in you example; but if you never declare it to be special then you are going to get warnings about how the compiler thinks you misspelled it.